# python3 configuration issue on sublimetext3

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have recently installed python3. I created a new build system and named it Python3.sublime-build and added the below,

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/“
}
```

The path is where my python3 installation files are found.

But when i select python3 and use the build function i get the error

```
No build system
```

Python 2.7 works fine. How can i fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: What if you try changing the path to `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you but that don't work. I can execute python3 from the terminal. It's just about configuring SublimeText3

Comment: Thanks again @MattDMo. Removing the `"path": "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/“` and changing the cmd entry from `python` to `/usr/local/bin/python3` seems to have resolved the issue.  It works fine with the encoding included as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the build system I use:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I don't set a `"path"`, instead I just put the full path to the `python3` binary in the `"cmd"` array. Theoretically, `"encoding"` shouldn't be necessary, so I'd try removing it for now until you get the build system working, then try adding it back in.